# Accessibility: Remove outline on <p> when focused

Tags: html, accessibility

To be clear I'm looking for the most accessible and best designed option in this. So no I don't remove my outline on buttons and links and anywhere where it is useful. But I'm working on making a Dialog work. for this I use this [example](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-practices-1.1/examples/dialog-modal/dialog.html). In this example the first `<p>` is focused when opening the dialog. As mentioned in the example:

> In this dialog, the first paragraph has tabindex=-1. The first paragraph is also contained inside the element that provides the dialog description, i.e., the element that is referenced by aria-describedby. With some screen readers, this may have one negative but relatively insignificant side effect when the dialog opens -- the first paragraph may be announced twice. Nonetheless, making the first paragraph focusable and setting the initial focus on it is the most broadly accessible option.

But off course this paragraph gets an outline because it is in focus. I was wondering if the element has an `tabindex=-1` and is not an element you can interact with. Is it allowed to remove the outline from this part?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Short Answer

You can safely remove the focus indicator on a paragraph with `tabindex="-1"` if you wish. There is a better way to handle nested modals though.

### Long Answer

WCAG is a little "wooly" (not specific enough) here in the way they describe things but the [guidance for focus indicators](https://www.w3.org/WAI/WCAG21/Understanding/focus-visible.html) is for "controls" or "interactive elements".

Also the main description of the criteria is

> Success Criterion 2.4.7 Focus Visible (Level AA): Any **keyboard operable** user interface has a mode of operation where the keyboard focus indicator is visible.

As you cannot interact with the paragraph (it is not keyboard operable) it is easy to argue that providing a focus indicator is actually more confusing as no standard actions will work. However, you could also argue that landing in a new modal without a focus indicator is also confusing.

As such this one is a judgement call, I always go for removing the focus indicator on elements that are not interactive if I need to focus them programatically, especially if pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> could submit a form etc.

#### Is there a better way to handle this that avoids the pitfalls of focusing a non-interactive element?

There is a way that you can fix all of these issues and still have a visible focus indicator.

We add the close button to the top of the modal (normally positioned top right) and use [`aria-describedby`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/ARIA_Techniques/Using_the_aria-describedby_attribute) pointed at the modal title.

```
<button id="dialog2_close_btn" aria-describedby="dialog2_label" onclick="closeDialog(this)">Close</button>
```

This will then read "Close Verification Result". Then we just focus that button instead of the modal title

```
<button onclick="openDialog('dialog2', this, 'dialog2_close_btn')">
  Verify Address
</button>
```

I have made the adjustments in the example below, if you click "Verify Address" once you have opened the first modal you will see that there is a close button at the top that is focused.

```js
/**
 * @namespace aria
 */

var aria = aria || {};

/**
 * @desc
 *  Key code constants
 */
aria.KeyCode = {
  BACKSPACE: 8,
  TAB: 9,
  RETURN: 13,
  ESC: 27,
  SPACE: 32,
  PAGE_UP: 33,
  PAGE_DOWN: 34,
  END: 35,
  HOME: 36,
  LEFT: 37,
  UP: 38,
  RIGHT: 39,
  DOWN: 40,
  DELETE: 46
};

aria.Utils = aria.Utils || {};

// Polyfill src https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/matches
aria.Utils.matches = function (element, selector) {
  if (!Element.prototype.matches) {
    Element.prototype.matches =
      Element.prototype.matchesSelector ||
      Element.prototype.mozMatchesSelector ||
      Element.prototype.msMatchesSelector ||
      Element.prototype.oMatchesSelector ||
      Element.prototype.webkitMatchesSelector ||
      function (s) {
        var matches = element.parentNode.querySelectorAll(s);
        var i = matches.length;
        while (--i >= 0 && matches.item(i) !== this) {}
        return i > -1;
      };
  }

  return element.matches(selector);
};

aria.Utils.remove = function (item) {
  if (item.remove && typeof item.remove === 'function') {
    return item.remove();
  }
  if (item.parentNode &&
      item.parentNode.removeChild &&
      typeof item.parentNode.removeChild === 'function') {
    return item.parentNode.removeChild(item);
  }
  return false;
};

aria.Utils.isFocusable = function (element) {
  if (element.tabIndex > 0 || (element.tabIndex === 0 && element.getAttribute('tabIndex') !== null)) {
    return true;
  }

  if (element.disabled) {
    return false;
  }

  switch (element.nodeName) {
    case 'A':
      return !!element.href && element.rel != 'ignore';
    case 'INPUT':
      return element.type != 'hidden' && element.type != 'file';
    case 'BUTTON':
    case 'SELECT':
    case 'TEXTAREA':
      return true;
    default:
      return false;
  }
};

aria.Utils.getAncestorBySelector = function (element, selector) {
  if (!aria.Utils.matches(element, selector + ' ' + element.tagName)) {
    // Element is not inside an element that matches selector
    return null;
  }

  // Move up the DOM tree until a parent matching the selector is found
  var currentNode = element;
  var ancestor = null;
  while (ancestor === null) {
    if (aria.Utils.matches(currentNode.parentNode, selector)) {
      ancestor = currentNode.parentNode;
    }
    else {
      currentNode = currentNode.parentNode;
    }
  }

  return ancestor;
};

aria.Utils.hasClass = function (element, className) {
  return (new RegExp('(\\s|^)' + className + '(\\s|$)')).test(element.className);
};

aria.Utils.addClass = function (element, className) {
  if (!aria.Utils.hasClass(element, className)) {
    element.className += ' ' + className;
  }
};

aria.Utils.removeClass = function (element, className) {
  var classRegex = new RegExp('(\\s|^)' + className + '(\\s|$)');
  element.className = element.className.replace(classRegex, ' ').trim();
};

aria.Utils.bindMethods = function (object /* , ...methodNames */) {
  var methodNames = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1);
  methodNames.forEach(function (method) {
    object[method] = object[method].bind(object);
  });
};


/*
*   This content is licensed according to the W3C Software License at
*   https://www.w3.org/Consortium/Legal/2015/copyright-software-and-document
*/

var aria = aria || {};

aria.Utils = aria.Utils || {};

(function () {
  /*
   * When util functions move focus around, set this true so the focus listener
   * can ignore the events.
   */
  aria.Utils.IgnoreUtilFocusChanges = false;

  aria.Utils.dialogOpenClass = 'has-dialog';

  /**
   * @desc Set focus on descendant nodes until the first focusable element is
   *       found.
   * @param element
   *          DOM node for which to find the first focusable descendant.
   * @returns
   *  true if a focusable element is found and focus is set.
   */
  aria.Utils.focusFirstDescendant = function (element) {
    for (var i = 0; i < element.childNodes.length; i++) {
      var child = element.childNodes[i];
      if (aria.Utils.attemptFocus(child) ||
          aria.Utils.focusFirstDescendant(child)) {
        return true;
      }
    }
    return false;
  }; // end focusFirstDescendant

  /**
   * @desc Find the last descendant node that is focusable.
   * @param element
   *          DOM node for which to find the last focusable descendant.
   * @returns
   *  true if a focusable element is found and focus is set.
   */
  aria.Utils.focusLastDescendant = function (element) {
    for (var i = element.childNodes.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
      var child = element.childNodes[i];
      if (aria.Utils.attemptFocus(child) ||
          aria.Utils.focusLastDescendant(child)) {
        return true;
      }
    }
    return false;
  }; // end focusLastDescendant

  /**
   * @desc Set Attempt to set focus on the current node.
   * @param element
   *          The node to attempt to focus on.
   * @returns
   *  true if element is focused.
   */
  aria.Utils.attemptFocus = function (element) {
    if (!aria.Utils.isFocusable(element)) {
      return false;
    }

    aria.Utils.IgnoreUtilFocusChanges = true;
    try {
      element.focus();
    }
    catch (e) {
    }
    aria.Utils.IgnoreUtilFocusChanges = false;
    return (document.activeElement === element);
  }; // end attemptFocus

  /* Modals can open modals. Keep track of them with this array. */
  aria.OpenDialogList = aria.OpenDialogList || new Array(0);

  /**
   * @returns the last opened dialog (the current dialog)
   */
  aria.getCurrentDialog = function () {
    if (aria.OpenDialogList && aria.OpenDialogList.length) {
      return aria.OpenDialogList[aria.OpenDialogList.length - 1];
    }
  };

  aria.closeCurrentDialog = function () {
    var currentDialog = aria.getCurrentDialog();
    if (currentDialog) {
      currentDialog.close();
      return true;
    }

    return false;
  };

  aria.handleEscape = function (event) {
    var key = event.which || event.keyCode;

    if (key === aria.KeyCode.ESC && aria.closeCurrentDialog()) {
      event.stopPropagation();
    }
  };

  document.addEventListener('keyup', aria.handleEscape);

  /**
   * @constructor
   * @desc Dialog object providing modal focus management.
   *
   * Assumptions: The element serving as the dialog container is present in the
   * DOM and hidden. The dialog container has role='dialog'.
   *
   * @param dialogId
   *          The ID of the element serving as the dialog container.
   * @param focusAfterClosed
   *          Either the DOM node or the ID of the DOM node to focus when the
   *          dialog closes.
   * @param focusFirst
   *          Optional parameter containing either the DOM node or the ID of the
   *          DOM node to focus when the dialog opens. If not specified, the
   *          first focusable element in the dialog will receive focus.
   */
  aria.Dialog = function (dialogId, focusAfterClosed, focusFirst) {
    this.dialogNode = document.getElementById(dialogId);
    if (this.dialogNode === null) {
      throw new Error('No element found with id="' + dialogId + '".');
    }

    var validRoles = ['dialog', 'alertdialog'];
    var isDialog = (this.dialogNode.getAttribute('role') || '')
      .trim()
      .split(/\s+/g)
      .some(function (token) {
        return validRoles.some(function (role) {
          return token === role;
        });
      });
    if (!isDialog) {
      throw new Error(
        'Dialog() requires a DOM element with ARIA role of dialog or alertdialog.');
    }

    // Wrap in an individual backdrop element if one doesn't exist
    // Native <dialog> elements use the ::backdrop pseudo-element, which
    // works similarly.
    var backdropClass = 'dialog-backdrop';
    if (this.dialogNode.parentNode.classList.contains(backdropClass)) {
      this.backdropNode = this.dialogNode.parentNode;
    }
    else {
      this.backdropNode = document.createElement('div');
      this.backdropNode.className = backdropClass;
      this.dialogNode.parentNode.insertBefore(this.backdropNode, this.dialogNode);
      this.backdropNode.appendChild(this.dialogNode);
    }
    this.backdropNode.classList.add('active');

    // Disable scroll on the body element
    document.body.classList.add(aria.Utils.dialogOpenClass);

    if (typeof focusAfterClosed === 'string') {
      this.focusAfterClosed = document.getElementById(focusAfterClosed);
    }
    else if (typeof focusAfterClosed === 'object') {
      this.focusAfterClosed = focusAfterClosed;
    }
    else {
      throw new Error(
        'the focusAfterClosed parameter is required for the aria.Dialog constructor.');
    }

    if (typeof focusFirst === 'string') {
      this.focusFirst = document.getElementById(focusFirst);
    }
    else if (typeof focusFirst === 'object') {
      this.focusFirst = focusFirst;
    }
    else {
      this.focusFirst = null;
    }

    // Bracket the dialog node with two invisible, focusable nodes.
    // While this dialog is open, we use these to make sure that focus never
    // leaves the document even if dialogNode is the first or last node.
    var preDiv = document.createElement('div');
    this.preNode = this.dialogNode.parentNode.insertBefore(preDiv,
      this.dialogNode);
    this.preNode.tabIndex = 0;
    var postDiv = document.createElement('div');
    this.postNode = this.dialogNode.parentNode.insertBefore(postDiv,
      this.dialogNode.nextSibling);
    this.postNode.tabIndex = 0;

    // If this modal is opening on top of one that is already open,
    // get rid of the document focus listener of the open dialog.
    if (aria.OpenDialogList.length > 0) {
      aria.getCurrentDialog().removeListeners();
    }

    this.addListeners();
    aria.OpenDialogList.push(this);
    this.clearDialog();
    this.dialogNode.className = 'default_dialog'; // make visible

    if (this.focusFirst) {
      this.focusFirst.focus();
    }
    else {
      aria.Utils.focusFirstDescendant(this.dialogNode);
    }

    this.lastFocus = document.activeElement;
  }; // end Dialog constructor

  aria.Dialog.prototype.clearDialog = function () {
    Array.prototype.map.call(
      this.dialogNode.querySelectorAll('input'),
      function (input) {
        input.value = '';
      }
    );
  };

  /**
   * @desc
   *  Hides the current top dialog,
   *  removes listeners of the top dialog,
   *  restore listeners of a parent dialog if one was open under the one that just closed,
   *  and sets focus on the element specified for focusAfterClosed.
   */
  aria.Dialog.prototype.close = function () {
    aria.OpenDialogList.pop();
    this.removeListeners();
    aria.Utils.remove(this.preNode);
    aria.Utils.remove(this.postNode);
    this.dialogNode.className = 'hidden';
    this.backdropNode.classList.remove('active');
    this.focusAfterClosed.focus();

    // If a dialog was open underneath this one, restore its listeners.
    if (aria.OpenDialogList.length > 0) {
      aria.getCurrentDialog().addListeners();
    }
    else {
      document.body.classList.remove(aria.Utils.dialogOpenClass);
    }
  }; // end close

  /**
   * @desc
   *  Hides the current dialog and replaces it with another.
   *
   * @param newDialogId
   *  ID of the dialog that will replace the currently open top dialog.
   * @param newFocusAfterClosed
   *  Optional ID or DOM node specifying where to place focus when the new dialog closes.
   *  If not specified, focus will be placed on the element specified by the dialog being replaced.
   * @param newFocusFirst
   *  Optional ID or DOM node specifying where to place focus in the new dialog when it opens.
   *  If not specified, the first focusable element will receive focus.
   */
  aria.Dialog.prototype.replace = function (newDialogId, newFocusAfterClosed,
    newFocusFirst) {
    var closedDialog = aria.getCurrentDialog();
    aria.OpenDialogList.pop();
    this.removeListeners();
    aria.Utils.remove(this.preNode);
    aria.Utils.remove(this.postNode);
    this.dialogNode.className = 'hidden';
    this.backdropNode.classList.remove('active');

    var focusAfterClosed = newFocusAfterClosed || this.focusAfterClosed;
    var dialog = new aria.Dialog(newDialogId, focusAfterClosed, newFocusFirst);
  }; // end replace

  aria.Dialog.prototype.addListeners = function () {
    document.addEventListener('focus', this.trapFocus, true);
  }; // end addListeners

  aria.Dialog.prototype.removeListeners = function () {
    document.removeEventListener('focus', this.trapFocus, true);
  }; // end removeListeners

  aria.Dialog.prototype.trapFocus = function (event) {
    if (aria.Utils.IgnoreUtilFocusChanges) {
      return;
    }
    var currentDialog = aria.getCurrentDialog();
    if (currentDialog.dialogNode.contains(event.target)) {
      currentDialog.lastFocus = event.target;
    }
    else {
      aria.Utils.focusFirstDescendant(currentDialog.dialogNode);
      if (currentDialog.lastFocus == document.activeElement) {
        aria.Utils.focusLastDescendant(currentDialog.dialogNode);
      }
      currentDialog.lastFocus = document.activeElement;
    }
  }; // end trapFocus

  window.openDialog = function (dialogId, focusAfterClosed, focusFirst) {
    var dialog = new aria.Dialog(dialogId, focusAfterClosed, focusFirst);
  };

  window.closeDialog = function (closeButton) {
    var topDialog = aria.getCurrentDialog();
    if (topDialog.dialogNode.contains(closeButton)) {
      topDialog.close();
    }
  }; // end closeDialog

  window.replaceDialog = function (newDialogId, newFocusAfterClosed,
    newFocusFirst) {
    var topDialog = aria.getCurrentDialog();
    if (topDialog.dialogNode.contains(document.activeElement)) {
      topDialog.replace(newDialogId, newFocusAfterClosed, newFocusFirst);
    }
  }; // end replaceDialog

}());
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}

[role="alertdialog"],
[role="dialog"] {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 15px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  background-color: #fff;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 640px) {
  [role="alertdialog"],
  [role="dialog"] {
    position: absolute;
    top: 2rem;
    left: 50vw;  /* move to the middle of the screen (assumes relative parent is the body/viewport) */
    transform: translateX(-50%);  /* move backwards 50% of this element's width */
    min-width: calc(640px - (15px * 2));  /* == breakpoint - left+right margin */
    min-height: auto;
    box-shadow: 0 19px 38px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12), 0 15px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.22);
  }
}

.dialog_label {
  text-align: center;
}

.dialog_form {
  margin: 15px;
}

.dialog_form .label_text {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding-right: 0.5em;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: bold;
  width: 30%;
  text-align: right;
}

.dialog_form .label_info {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding-right: 0.5em;
  font-size: 12px;
  width: 30%;
  text-align: right;
  display: inline-block;
}

.dialog_form_item {
  margin: 10px 0;
  font-size: 0;
}

.dialog_form_item .wide_input {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  max-width: 70%;
  width: 27em;
}

.dialog_form_item .city_input {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  max-width: 70%;
  width: 17em;
}

.dialog_form_item .state_input {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  max-width: 70%;
  width: 15em;
}

.dialog_form_item .zip_input {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  max-width: 70%;
  width: 9em;
}

.dialog_form_actions {
  text-align: right;
  padding: 0 20px 20px;
}

.dialog_close_button {
  float: right;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 92%;
  height: 25px;
}

.dialog_close_button img {
  border: 0;
}

.dialog_desc {
  padding: 10px 20px;
}

/* native <dialog> element uses the ::backdrop pseudo-element */

/* dialog::backdrop, */
.dialog-backdrop {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  overflow-y: auto;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 640px) {
  .dialog-backdrop {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  }
}

.dialog-backdrop.active {
  display: block;
}

.no-scroll {
  overflow-y: auto !important;
}

/* this is added to the body when a dialog is open */
.has-dialog {
  overflow: hidden;
}

/* styling for alert-dialog example */
.notes {
  display: block;
  font-size: 1rem;
  line-height: 1.3;
  min-width: 400px;
  max-width: 100%;
  width: 33%;
}

.toast {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
  color: #fff;
  padding: 1rem;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 0.25rem;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16), 0 3px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.23);
  position: fixed;
  top: 1rem;
  right: 1rem;
  transform: translateY(-150%);
  transition: transform 225ms cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1);
}

.toast.active {
  transform: translateY(0);
}
```

```html
<button onclick="openDialog('dialog1', this)">
  Add Delivery Address
</button>
<div role="dialog"
     id="dialog1"
     aria-labelledby="dialog1_label"
     aria-modal="true"
     class="hidden">
  <h2 id="dialog1_label" class="dialog_label">
    Add Delivery Address
  </h2>
  <div class="dialog_form">
    <div class="dialog_form_item">
      <label>
        <span class="label_text">
          Street:
        </span>
        <input type="text" class="wide_input">
      </label>
    </div>
    <div class="dialog_form_item">
      <label>
        <span class="label_text">
          City:
        </span>
        <input type="text" class="city_input">
      </label>
    </div>
    <div class="dialog_form_item">
      <label>
        <span class="label_text">
          State:
        </span>
        <input type="text" class="state_input">
      </label>
    </div>
    <div class="dialog_form_item">
      <label>
        <span class="label_text">
          Zip:
        </span>
        <input type="text" class="zip_input">
      </label>
    </div>
    <div class="dialog_form_item">
      <label for="special_instructions">
        <span class="label_text">
          Special instructions:
        </span>
      </label>
      <input id="special_instructions"
             type="text"
             aria-describedby="special_instructions_desc"
             class="wide_input">
      <div class="label_info" id="special_instructions_desc">
        For example, gate code or other information to help the driver find you
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="dialog_form_actions">
    <button onclick="openDialog('dialog2', this, 'dialog2_close_btn')">
      Verify Address
    </button>
    <button onclick="replaceDialog('dialog3', undefined, 'dialog3_close_btn')">
      Add
    </button>
    <button onclick="closeDialog(this)">
      Cancel
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
<!--  Second modal to open on top of the first modal  -->
<div id="dialog2"
     role="dialog"
     aria-labelledby="dialog2_label"
     aria-describedby="dialog2_desc"
     aria-modal="true"
     class="hidden">
     <button id="dialog2_close_btn" aria-describedby="dialog2_label" onclick="closeDialog(this)">Close</button>
  <h2 id="dialog2_label" class="dialog_label">
    Verification Result
  </h2>
  <div id="dialog2_desc" class="dialog_desc">
    <p tabindex="-1" id="dialog2_para1">
      This is just a demonstration. If it were a real application, it would
      provide a message telling whether the entered address is valid.
    </p>
    <p>
      For demonstration purposes, this dialog has a lot of text. It demonstrates a
        scenario where:
    </p>
    <ul>
      <li>
        The first interactive element, the help link, is at the bottom of the dialog.
      </li>
      <li>
        If focus is placed on the first interactive element when the dialog opens, the
        validation message may not be visible.
      </li>
      <li>
        If the validation message is visible and the focus is on the help link, then
        the focus may not be visible.
      </li>
      <li>
        When the dialog opens, it is important that both:
        <ul>
          <li>
            The beginning of the text is visible so users do not have to scroll back to
            start reading.
          </li>
          <li>
            The keyboard focus always remains visible.
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <p>
      There are several ways to resolve this issue:
    </p>
    <ul>
      <li>
        Place an interactive element at the top of the dialog, e.g., a button or link.
      </li>
      <li>
        Make a static element focusable, e.g., the dialog title or the first block of
        text.
      </li>
    </ul>
    <p>
      Please
      <em>
        DO NOT
      </em>
      make the element with role dialog focusable!
    </p>
    <ul>
      <li>
        The larger a focusable element is, the more difficult it is to visually
        identify the location of focus, especially for users with a narrow field of view.
      </li>
      <li>
        The dialog has a visual border, so creating a clear visual indicator of focus
        when the entire dialog has focus is not very feasible.
      </li>
      <li>
        Screen readers read the label and content of focusable elements. The dialog
        contains its label and a lot of content! If a dialog like this one has focus, the
        actual focus is difficult to comprehend.
      </li>
    </ul>
    <p>
      In this dialog, the first paragraph has
      <code>
        tabindex=
        <q>
          -1
        </q>
      </code>
      . The first
      paragraph is also contained inside the element that provides the dialog description, i.e., the element that is referenced
      by
      <code>
        aria-describedby
      </code>
      . With some screen readers, this may have one negative
      but relatively insignificant side effect when the dialog opens -- the first paragraph
      may be announced twice. Nonetheless, making the first paragraph focusable and setting
      the initial focus on it is the most broadly accessible option.
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="dialog_form_actions">
    <a href="#" onclick="openDialog('dialog4', this)">
      link to help
    </a>
    <button onclick="openDialog('dialog4', this)">
      accepting an alternative form
    </button>
    <button onclick="closeDialog(this)">
      Close
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
<!--  Dialog that replaces dialog 1.  -->
<div id="dialog3"
     role="dialog"
     aria-labelledby="dialog3_label"
     aria-describedby="dialog3_desc"
     aria-modal="true"
     class="hidden">
  <h2 id="dialog3_label" class="dialog_label">
    Address Added
  </h2>
  <p id="dialog3_desc" class="dialog_desc">
    The address you provided has been added to your list of delivery addresses. It is ready
    for immediate use. If you wish to remove it, you can do so from
    <a href="#" onclick="openDialog('dialog4', this)">
      your profile.
    </a>
  </p>
  <div class="dialog_form_actions">
    <button id="dialog3_close_btn" onclick="closeDialog(this)">
      OK
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="dialog4"
     role="dialog"
     aria-labelledby="dialog4_label"
     aria-describedby="dialog4_desc"
     class="hidden"
     aria-modal="true">
  <h2 id="dialog4_label" class="dialog_label">
    End of the Road!
  </h2>
  <p id="dialog4_desc" class="dialog_desc">
    You activated a fake link or button that goes nowhere!
    The link or button is present for demonstration purposes only.
  </p>
  <div class="dialog_form_actions">
    <button id="dialog4_close_btn" onclick="closeDialog(this)">
      Close
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
```